# Convert array to JSON in extJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, extjs4

I have a multiselect combobox in my extJS form.

It returns an array of strings on submit.

I want to convert it the array to json(in a particular format).

Eg. It returns in the following array:

```
categories : ['ABC','XYZ']
```

I want the JSON in the following format:

```
"categories":[{"name":"ABC"},{"name":"XYZ"}]
```

Are there any methods in ExtJs to do this?
How to achieve this using javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method in vanilla JS:

```
var out = JSON.stringify(categories.map(function (el) {
  return { name: el };
}));
```

**Output**

```
[{"name":"ABC"},{"name":"XYZ"}]
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WwvZR/)**

Answer (score 1):

Why not use

```
selected = [];
Ext.each(categories, function (item) {

   selected.push({
          'name': item
   });
});

Ext.encode(selected)
```